# Why does my dynamodb ContionExpression not prevent the update

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynampodb item that looks like this:

```
{
'id': 'some_id',
'task_states': {
    'some_task_id': {
        'phase': 'FINISHED'
     }
}
```

Now I am updating this with the conditions expression:

```
task_states.some_task_id.phase IN ('ABSENT','STARTING','RUNNING')
```

and the update takes place! But my condition should fail, because `task_states.some_task_id.phase` is `FINISHED` and therefore not in `('ABSENT','STARTING','RUNNING')`.

I do not get what is wrong here.

**Update**:

Here is the complete boto call:

```
        boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table("my_table").update_item(
            Key={
                "id": "some_id",
            },
            UpdateExpression="SET task_states.some_task_id.phase = :p",
            ExpressionAttributeValues=ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ":p": newPhase
            },
            ConditionExpression="task_states.some_task_id.phase IN ('ABSENT','STARTING','RUNNING')"
        )
```

Comment: Are you using Expression Atrribute Names for task_states.some_task_id.phase such like { #phase: task_states.some_task_id.phase }?

Comment: No, should? I tried, it did not help.

Comment: Not necessarily but if you were using it you might be getting caught on expression names. Read how nested attribute names has special conditions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html#Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.NestedAttributes